# How to solve "payable" from the code and a new error came "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" on solidity with truffle?

Tags: solidity, truffle

Disclaimer I am very new to coding and trying my hardest to break into this space. However, I am having issues with msg.value. On my version of solidity, I have had a lot of issues msg.value. I am using Truffle Suite for this project which is based on a tutorial from [Dapp University](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8rhueOcTu8k&t=3760s). When compiled I come back with:

"Error: Provided address "undefined" is invalid, the capitalization checksum test failed, or its an indrect IBAN address which can't be converted."

I did some research and found it could be a difference in the Solidity version I am using versus the one used in the video (0.4.0 vs 0.5.16) However I created more problems than I solved when trying to fix that. Perks of being a newbie.

This could be a simple fix as I mentioned I am just learning but anything anyone can tell me would be great for me to keep learning. Thank you in advance.

----------------------------------------------Updates-------------------------------------------------------

1. I removed "payable" from the code and a new error came "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.22;

contract Decentragram {
  string public name = "Decentragram";

    // Store Images
uint public imageCount = 0;
mapping(uint => Image) public images;

struct Image {
  uint id;
  string hash;
  string description;
  uint tipAmount;
  address author;
}

event ImageCreated(
  uint id,
  string hash,
  string description,
  uint tipAmount,
  address author
  );

event ImageTipped(
  uint id,
  string hash,
  string description,
  uint tipAmount,
  address author
  );

  // Create Images
function uploadImage(string memory _imgHash, string memory _description) public {

  // Make sure Image Description exists
  require(bytes(_description).length > 0);

  // Make sure Image hash exists
  require(bytes(_imgHash).length > 0);

  // Make sure uploader address exists
  require(msg.sender != address(0));


  //Increment Image ID
  imageCount ++;

  // Add Image to Contract
  images[imageCount] = Image(imageCount, _imgHash, _description, 0, msg.sender);

    // Trigger an event
  emit ImageCreated(imageCount, _imgHash, _description, 0, msg.sender);
}
  // Tip Images
  function tipImageOwner (uint _id) public {
    //Make sure the ID is valid
    require(_id > 0 && _id <= imageCount);
    // Fetch the image 
    Image memory _image = images[_id];
    //Fetch the author
    address _author = _image.author;

    // Pay the author by sending them Ether
    address(_author).transfer(msg.value); 

    // Increment the tip amount
    _image.tipAmount = _image.tipAmount + msg.value;
    // Update the Image
    images[_id] = _image;
    //Trigger an event
    emit ImageTipped(_id, _image.hash, _image.description, _image.tipAmount, _author);
  }
}
```

Comment: What problems did you cause when you updated the solidity version?  What error are you dealing with now?

Comment: I actually solved the version issue but now I am met with this error. 

> Compiling .\src\contracts\Decentragram.sol

/C/Users/User/decentragram/src/contracts/Decentragram.sol:15:11: Error: Expected identifier, got 'Payable'
  address payable author;
          ^
,/C/Users/User/decentragram/src/contracts/Migrations.sol:7:14: Error: Expected identifier, got 'LParen'
  constructor() public {

Comment: you can remove payable for pragma v0.4x. It's not needed with address until version 5

Comment: I took out payable in my code and am met with "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"